# Thread ends while catching exception C#

Tags: c#, exception, argumentexception

So I have a stack of calls. At the end of the stack an ArgumentException gets thrown. It propogates from to the last but one point where I have this code:

```
    ... Constructor(..){
        try
        {
            this.Issuer = issuer;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Secret = secret;
            this.totpObj = new Totp(secret, 30, 6, mode);
            this.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            this.mode = mode;
            this.valid = true;
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException e)
        {
            throw e; // Also tried not having this --> option B

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

And this code gets called from here:

```
private void addButtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
          ...
          TOTPObj totpo = new TOTPObj(af.Accname, af.Issuer, secret, stype); // <--- FAILS
          ...
       }
       catch(Exception ex) //  <--- SHOULD CATCH THIS?!
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex);
           Environment.Exit(ERROR_FAILED_ADD_KEY);
       }
   }
```

Now if I leave the "throw" in the first section of code I get:
[image]

While I think it should be caught at the next level? (second fragment of code).

If I don't throw the exception up but just do stuff there, I never get past the "<--- FAILS" point of code block two, the thread just exits. Why is that?

Comment: Just use `throw` instead of `throw e`, to avoid mangling the call stack, not that this would fix your problem. Constructors should NEVER throw exceptions. Create a factory method instead.

Comment: How would creating the factory change that? I'd just then make a blank instance of the class and then fill in the arguments using the setters and get the exception to be thrown there instead? The issue itself can't be related to having the throw in my contructor? Or can it? And why should you never do so?

Also why if I catch the exception in my constructor (and dont' throw it) the UI thread ends?

Comment: This is just not possible with the code you have shown us. The only exception that might cause your problem may be a stack overflow.

Comment: I assume that empty catch (Exception) in `Constructor` is not really empty and you're sure that one isn't triggered for some reason?

Comment: Yeah I added it after the issue started occuring, just in case. Also as can be seen in the images, it's the other one the "specific" exception that gets triggered, on the "throw" line

Comment: you talk about threads in the question title, but I do not see any threads being started in the code?